# Gradle 6 settings.gradle.kts properties problem

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

please help me understand what was changed in Gradle 6 so the following code doesn't work anymore (worked well in Gradle 5):

```
val artifactoryUser: String by settings
val artifactoryPassword: String by settings

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://internal-artifactory")
            credentials {
                username = artifactoryUser
                password = artifactoryPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have an error: "Unresolved reference: artifactoryUser".

This problem can be solved by moving properties declaration inside the pluginManagement block

```
pluginManagement {
val artifactoryUser: String by settings
val artifactoryPassword: String by settings
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://internal-artifactory")
            credentials {
                username = artifactoryUser
                password = artifactoryPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for it is mentioned in the [Grade 6 upgrade notes](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#the_pluginmanagement_block_in_settings_scripts_is_now_isolated) :

> **The pluginManagement block in settings scripts is now isolated**
>
> Previously, any pluginManagement {} blocks inside a settings script
>   were executed during the normal execution of the script.
>
> Now, they are executed earlier in a similar manner to buildscript {}
>   or plugins {}. This means that code inside such a block cannot
>   reference anything declared elsewhere in the script.
>
> This change has been made so that pluginManagement configuration can
>   also be applied when resolving plugins for the settings script itself.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, moving the `val` inside the pluginManagement block does the trick, when migrating from Gradle 5.x to Gradle 6.x.

```kotlin
val kotlinVersion: String by settings

pluginManagement {
...
}
```

to:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    val kotlinVersion: String by settings
...
}
```